# How to pass a Array as a parameter in this procedure?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, overloading, procedure

I have this procedure:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Append text to the current text.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="text">The text to append</param>
    ''' <param name="forecolor">The font color</param>
    ''' <param name="backcolor">The Background color</param>
    ''' <param name="font">The font of the text</param>
    Public Sub Append_Text(ByVal text As String, _
                          ByVal forecolor As Color, _
                          Optional ByVal backcolor As Color = Nothing, _
                          Optional ByVal font As Font = Nothing)

        Dim index As Int32 = MyBase.TextLength
        MyBase.AppendText(text)
        MyBase.SelectionStart = index
        MyBase.SelectionLength = MyBase.TextLength - index
        MyBase.SelectionColor = forecolor
        If Not backcolor = Nothing Then MyBase.SelectionBackColor = backcolor
        If font IsNot Nothing Then MyBase.SelectionFont = font
        MyBase.SelectionStart = MyBase.TextLength
        MyBase.SelectionLength = 0

    End Sub
```

I call the procedure like this:

```
RichTextLabel1.Append_Text("My ", Color.White, color.transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold))
RichTextLabel1.Append_Text("RichText-", Color.White, , New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold))
```

My question is if I can make an overload (and how to do the modifications) to call the proc just once by using an array of parameters like this:

```
RichTextLabel1.Append_Text( _
{"My ", Color.White, Color.Transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)}, _
{"RichTextLabel", Color.White, Nothing, New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold)})
```

(That piece of code don't works obviously)

Comment: The only way to do what you ask is to have an 2-dimensional or jagged array of `Object`, so there will be no type safety. Why is calling the method twice so bad? It's good enough as it is.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks for comment, just I wanted to simplify the usage of the proc to don't write too much lines of code and to not call too much the proc, maybe I was too optimist this time 'cause by your words it seems to be hard to do that modification, maybe if you can explain me more about this: " 2-dimensional or jagged array of Object"

Comment: See my answer. I've tried to illustrate the use of each option as well as give a detailed explanation of the problems with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do this using a [two-dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/02e7z943.aspx):

```
Public Sub Append_Text(ByVal parameters As Object(,))
    If UBound(parameters, 2) <> 3 Then
        Throw new ArgumentException("Array was not the correct size", "parameters")
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(parameters, 1)
        Append_Text( _
            CType(parameters(i, 0), String), _
            CType(parameters(i, 1), Color), _
            CType(parameters(i, 2), Color), _
            CType(parameters(i, 3), Font))
    Next
End Sub

RichTextLabel1.Append_Text({ _
    {"My ", Color.White, Color.Transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)}, _
    {"RichTextLabel", Color.White, Nothing, New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold)} _
})
```

Or this using a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_JaggedArrays):

```
Public Sub Append_Text(ByVal parameters As Object()())
    For Each p In parameters
        If UBound(p) <> 3 Then
            Throw new ArgumentException("Array was not the correct size", "parameters")
        End If

        Append_Text( _
            CType(p(i)(0), String), _
            CType(p(i)(1), Color), _
            CType(p(i)(2), Color), _
            CType(p(i)(3), Font))
    Next
End Sub

RichTextLabel1.Append_Text({ _
    New Object(){"My ", Color.White, Color.Transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)}, _
    New Object(){"RichTextLabel", Color.White, Nothing, New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold)} _
})
```

But the closest thing to what you're asking is a jagged array with the [`ParamArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct363x9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword:

```
Public Sub Append_Text(ByVal ParamArray parameters As Object()())
    ' Same as Above
End Sub

RichTextLabel1.Append_Text( _
    {"My ", Color.White, Color.Transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)}, _
    {"RichTextLabel", Color.White, Nothing, New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold)})
```

Of course, the problem with all of cases is that you completely loose compile-time type safety. There's nothing preventing a user from passing in an argument of the wrong type, or the wrong number of parameters (although I've added simple run-time checks to illustrate how to do that). Ultimately, if the goal is to reduce the number of lines of code needed to add multiple items, note that simply calling the method twice is actually fewer lines of code that what you're asking for:

```
' 2 lines of code
RichTextLabel1.Append_Text("My ", Color.White, Color.Transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold))
RichTextLabel1.Append_Text("RichTextLabel", Color.White, Nothing, New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold))

' 3 lines of code
RichTextLabel1.Append_Text( _
    {"My ", Color.White, Color.Transparent, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)}, _
    {"RichTextLabel", Color.White, Nothing, New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold)})
```

Comment: thanks, the jagged array example is not working, it throws an error on "p", the first is working but can you tell me how to pass that 2.dimensional array to the procedure? I've read the first and second links but I can't understand the part of passing the arrays, I've tried it mixing the usage of , {} and ().

Comment: @ElektroHacker Sorry about that, see my updated answer. I've also included examples on how to call each version.